# Jquery validation for positioning divs with text input fields

Tags: jquery, html, validation, onchange, each

I have 5 text inputs with position values from (1-5). I am trying to find a way that will only allow the user to enter in a value 1 through 5 in the text fields to get their desired position settings but it must have all values 1-5

EXA:

| 1 | | 2 | | 3 | | 4 | | 5 |

If user changes "2" to "5" then the result should look like this:

| 1 | | 5 | | 3 | | 4 | | 2 |

This is going to be used to re-order the position of divs.

```
<input class='position' id='31' type='text' value='3'>
<input class='position' id='10' type='text' value='4'>
<input class='position' id='29' type='text' value='1'>
<input class='position' id='12' type='text' value='5'>
<input class='position' id='30' type='text' value='2'>
```

Currently, I have a change function for each input that has a .each function within it to check for duplicate values. There is a ajax that is fired for each input change.

```
    $(".position").change(function(){

    var current_val = this.value;
    var current_id = this.id;


    $(".position").each(function() {

        if ( $(this).val() == current_val) {
        alert("duplicate");
        return false;
        }

    });
```

I am not quite sure on how to handle the value changes for the input fields.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.focusin` and a data attribute to accomplish what you want to do, as follows:

- when the page loads, save the current value to `data-value`
- when an `input` is focused, save the current value to `data-value`
- when an `input` changes, determine the input that had it's new value and give it the changed `input`'s old value (**exchange**)
- you would have to implement some validation to ensure the user does not type any value outside the range `[1,5]`.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.position').each(function() {
        $(this).data('value', this.value);
    })
    .on('focusin', function() {
        $(this).data('value', this.value);
    })
    .on('change', function() {
        var thisVal = this.value;
        $('.position').not(this).filter(function() {
            return this.value == thisVal;
        })
        .val( $(this).data('value') );
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.position').each(function() {
        $(this).data('value', this.value);
    })
    .on('focusin', function() {
        $(this).data('value', this.value);
    })
    .on('change', function() {
        var thisVal = this.value;
        $('.position').not(this).filter(function() {
            return this.value == thisVal;
        })
        .val( $(this).data('value') );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='position' id='31' type='text' value='3'>
<input class='position' id='10' type='text' value='4'>
<input class='position' id='29' type='text' value='1'>
<input class='position' id='12' type='text' value='5'>
<input class='position' id='30' type='text' value='2'>
```

Comment: Great! Glad you found this helpful. Enjoy!